# $f$ is product and $ \sum_{d|n}f(d)=(1+a_1t)...(1+a_kt) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

suppose $t \in \Bbb R$ ,definition of $f$ is :$f(1)=1$ ,also,if $n=p_1^{a_1}...p_k^{a_k}$ then we define $f(n)=t^k$

how to prove : $f$ is a multiplicative arithmetic function and $ \sum_{d|n}f(d)=(1+a_1t)...(1+a_kt) $

Comment: "f is product"? Do you mean $\,f\,$ is a multiplicative arithmetic function?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $f$ is a multiplicative function. To show this, note that if $n = ab$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime, then the prime factors of $n$ are split between $a$ and $b$. If $k$ primes divide $n$, $k_1$ primes divide $a$ and $k_2$ primes divide $b$, we have $k_1 + k_2 = k$. Therefore
$$f(n) = t^k = t^{k_1}t^{k_2}=f(a)f(b)$$
Let $F(n)$ denote the sum. It follows that $F$ is also multiplicative. For a prime power $p^a$, we have
$$F(p^a) = f(1) + f(p) + f(p^2) + \cdots + f(p^a) = 1+\underbrace{t+t+\cdots+t}_{a\ \text{times}}=1+at$$
Therefore if $n$ has prime factorization $$n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$$
it follows that we have
$$F(n) = F(p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}) = F(p_1^{a_1})\cdots F(p_k^{a_k})=(1+a_1t)\cdots(1+a_kt)$$